# Magento2 Admin Validate class not found from basename 'StringLength'

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento-upgrade

Hello I have upgrade magento version from Magento235 to Magento242
now if i am trying to save product attributes from Stores->attributes->product
than it shows Validate class not found from basename 'StringLength' error.

can anyone have about this ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in your `php.ini` file

> include_path =
> ".:/yourpathtomagento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library"

Add your Magento Root directory path where I have mentioned yourpathtomagento in the above path and then check.

- Note: Go to your console and move into your Magento installation
  directory and then run `PWD` command there and copy the whole path
  and paste there instead of this text `yourpathtomagento`.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: i already refer this block @meet than also getting this errror